# Remove one page from Search Results

Tags: 2013, search-results, query

We have a subsite with its own search result source (scope) "This site." The scope is only available on the site. So people who use it will be on the site.

For many searches the site home page comes up as the top item returned -- which isn't so helpful because they are already on the site.

I want to either eliminate it from the results entirely or push it to the bottom. Either is fine.

I thought I could go into the query builder for my result source and do something like:

```
-https://oursite/managedpath/collection/subsite/Pages/default.aspx
```

But that doesn't remove it from the results. And it might be because it is returning the "site" not the "page."

All the tutorials I find are how to eliminate whole sites or classes of things. I just want to eliminate this one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query builder, try using the Sorting tab and sort by rank then use the Dynamic Ordering property and set it to Demote to bottom.  As long as you can get the query to hit that one page it should show up as the last result.

I know it is not getting rid of the link, but at least the user would have to wade through everything before getting to it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to write it myself in the query and wasn't getting it. The Sorting screen makes a nice interface which can generate XRANK(cb=-7500.00) Path="https://path..." and yeah I don't care if the result is there, I just don't want it first!

Comment: Great!  glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same situation as we were trying wanted to expose a page to the public (more specifically internal users) but not promote it through out site-wide search or Google and I think I was able to find a solution.

If you edit the page, go to the "Page" tab and then go to "Edit SEO Properties", you can find meta descriptions and keywords etc. At the very bottom there is a radio selection where you can choose to not include on the Sitemap and Internet Search Enginges.

[image]

This all being said, I have yet to test if it shows up in Google searches or Site-wide searches, but this seems very promising.

*Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the search settings of my Office 365 tenant, I'm not sure how or where it translates to an on prem central admin yet, but there is an option to Exclude URLs from search results. You'd want to do that there. Then it removes the content from the index entirely.

Comment: Don't have access to central admin. Just the result source query builder. And we do want it in the Everything farm search, just not for within its own scope.